# Match nested subdirectories with a Scotty RoutePattern

Tags: haskell, scotty

I'm serving some static files with my Scotty webserver. They can also be located in subdirectories. My current approach looks like this:

```
get "/:fileName" $ do
    fileName <- param "fileName"
    file $ pathToStaticFiles </> fileName

get "/:dirName/:fileName" $ do
    dirName <- param "dirName"
    fileName <- param "fileName"
    file $ pathToStaticFiles </> dirName </> fileName

get "/:dirName1/:dirName2/:fileName" $ do
    dirName1 <- param "dirName1"
    dirName2 <- param "dirName2"
    fileName <- param "fileName"
    file $ pathToStaticFiles </> dirName1 </> dirName2 </> fileName

....
```

Is there a possibility to match paths with different directory nesting depth using only one single pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scotty has several other route patterns on top of the default one (which is called `capture`). Those can be found in [the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.9.1/docs/Web-Scotty.html#g:3).

`regex` seems to be exactly what you want. Here is the example from the documentation :

```
get (regex "^/f(.*)r$") $ do
   path <- param "0"
   cap <- param "1"
   text $ mconcat ["Path: ", path, "\nCapture: ", cap]
```

For your use case, it'd be a matter of catching the whole path, splitting on "/" and folding the resulting list with `</>`.